# ajax call successful but no values in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

ajax  success function alert data but on php side  no data there GET array is  empty

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var  array={
    name:"amr",
    age:22
}
array =JSON.stringify(array);
$.ajax({
    url :"new.php",
    type : "GET",
    data :  {action:array},
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
    },

});
</script>



<?php 
$var =json_encode($_GET['action']);
echo $var;
?>
```

[image]

Comment: How did you get the error in the browser? you just loaded the page?

Comment: I think the problem is that you just loaded the php file in the browser, but it's not the same as the ajax request. To emulate the ajax request you need to load the page like: http://localhost/ajax.php?action=test

Comment: Is the PHP code at the bottom in `new.php` or `ajax.php`?

Comment: You're getting the error in `ajax.php`, not the script that receives the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code is executed on the server, the output of PHP is then sent to the client, the client executes JavaScript, not PHP. In your example you have two pages, `ajax.php` and `new.php`, in this example you don't need to use PHP in `ajax.php` page, since once the PHP present in ajax.php is executed on server and the output is sent to the client it will not change anymore.

This code:

```
<?php 
$var =json_encode($_GET['action']);
echo $var;
?>
```

should be into your `new.php` file, and only there, `ajax.php` will call from the client `new.php`, that will execute your PHP and will send back the output to the client, once you have the output on the client you can do with it whatever you want, for example this may be the source code in your `ajax.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var  array={
    name:"amr",
    age:22
}
array =JSON.stringify(array);
$.ajax({
    url :"new.php",
    type : "GET",
    data :  {action:array},
    success: function(response){
    /*
     * This will write on your page (ajax.php) the response 
     * from the server, note that this is done with javascript,
     * not with PHP
     */
        document.write(response);
    },

});
</script>
```

You can also rename the file `ajax.php` to `ajax.html`, since no PHP is needed on this page.